# simple bank account in python

Tags: python-3.x

How do I create a function that save and update the transaction made that when I close the program and run it again , the accounts will show the last transaction that was made before the programme ended.

```
Account(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 0

    def deposit(self, amount):
        if (amount < 0):
            return 'Please deposit an amount greater than 0'
            self.balance += amount
            print ('Amount deposited {}'.format(amount))
            return 'SUCCESS'

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if (amount < 0):
            return 'Please withdraw an amount greater than 0'
        if (amount > self.balance):
    return
```

Comment: Your indentations are messed up. Please fix it.

Comment: You can write your last transactions to file or a database. The former is easier

Comment: Ok thanks but how to do it ? Can I get a sample code as to how it's done ?